# Can I incorporate SSIS into my cloud application?

Tags: c#, ssis, cloud, etl, data-migration

First the generalized problem:
I need to make an ETL solution that users will be able to launch from a cloud application. I would like to make a solution where they do some simple mapping and my program does the rest. They shouldn't be able to see my DB, nor, ideally, should I see or even really care about their data source. The goal is a hands off approach. Assumptions are that the data sources are Access, Excel or even Word and follow a somewhat standard layout.

For the specifics, our application uses C# on the .NET framework. We'll be using Azure to host our application and SQL Azure to host our DB. I'm looking into using SSIS to set up the main part of the ETL portion, throw some type of front end that's more customized for our users, and having that launch to do all the necessary ETL function.

This is to be done once per user, however each user needs their own DB and each user will have a different legacy system.

Can I use SSIS in this way or do I need a different solution. Does anyone know how hard it is to write your own customized ETL? If you know of any other ways of dealing with this problem, I'd be very interested in hearing about them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Microsoft cloud offering for SSIS as a part of SQL Azure.  I know *SSRS* beta is coming next year, however, have heard no news of SSIS.

So, if you want to utilize SQL Azure, I suggest either:

- Hosting SSIS locally and connecting
  your Azure deployment to your local
  SSIS (this may not be very reliable
  or scalable)
- Design your own ETL infrastructure. 
  There are many ways to do this,
  depending on how complex your needs
  are, and how comprehensive of a
  solution you need
- Find a cloud-based ETL provider. 
  There are a number of them if you
  google around, but I dont have any
  personal recommendations